# NHibernate IQueryOver.ToRowCountQuery() equivalent when Using HQL IQuery

Tags: nhibernate, hql, paging

I'm trying to implement paging within my project.

When using NHibernate's IQueryOver syntax as shown below things are working as expected.

```
    public PagedResult<T> ExecutePagedQuery(IQueryOver<T,T> query)
    {
        SetPaging(query);

        var results = query.Future<T>();
        var count = query.ToRowCountQuery().FutureValue<int>();

        return new PagedResult<T>()
        {
            TotalItemCount = count.Value,
            PageOfResults = results.ToList()
        };
    }

    protected virtual void SetPaging(IQueryOver<T, T> query)
    {
        var maxResults = PageSize;
        var numberToSkip = (PageNumber - 1) * PageSize;

        query.Skip(numberToSkip).Take(maxResults);
    }
```

For some queries we are using HQL instead of the IQueryOver syntax however.

I'm wondering if there is an equivalent to "query.ToRowCountQuery().FutureValue< int >()"  that can be used when querying when passing an IQuery insead of an IQueryOver to provide the row count.

```
    public PagedResult<T> ExecutePagedQuery(IQuery query)
    {
        SetPaging(query);

        var results = query.Future<T>();
        var count = // ToRowCountQueryEquivalent?

        return new PagedResult<T>()
        {
            TotalItemCount = count,
            PageOfResults = results.ToList()
        };
    }

    protected virtual void SetPaging(IQuery query)
    {
        var maxResults = PageSize;
        var numberToSkip = (PageNumber - 1) * PageSize;

        query.SetFirstResult(numberToSkip);
        query.SetMaxResults(maxResults);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

some crazy idea

```
string countQuery;
if (query.QueryString.StartsWith("SELECT", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    countQuery = Regex.Replace(query.QueryString, "SELECT (.*) FROM", @"SELECT Count($1) FROM", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
else
    countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) " + query.QueryString;
```

Answer (score 0):

We've since converted our HQL queries to IQueryOver allowing us to take advantage of the ToRowCountQuery() helper.

Comment: Which is buggy. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012966/torowcountquery-seems-to-ignore-groupings